# Mutiple skipping indices on one column in clickhouse

Tags: sql, indexing, clickhouse

for example:

```sql
-- create a test table
CREATE TABLE event_test
(
    `ts` DateTime64,
    `cuid` String,
    INDEX idx_cuid_mx cuid TYPE minmax GRANULARITY 10,
    INDEX idx_cuid_blm cuid TYPE bloom_filter GRANULARITY 100
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(ts)
ORDER BY (ts)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

When I exec sql like this: "select * from event_test where cuid = 'xxx' ",
what's the execution logic? idx_cuid_mx or idx_cuid_blm first